# How to merge dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "A": ["A1", "A1", "A2", "A3"],
    "B": ["B0", "B1", "B2", "B3"],
    "C": ["C0", "C1", "C2", "C3"],
    "D": ["D0", "D1", "D2", "D3"],},
    index=[0, 1, 2, 3])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "A": ["A1", "A22", "A2", "A3"],
    "C": ["C0", "C231", "C2", "C3"],
    "B": ["B0", "B1", "B34", "B2313"],
    "D": ["D0", "D1", "D2", "D3"],},
    index=[0, 1, 2, 3])
```

What do I need to do in order to get a dataframe with the similar values, but where the values are not matched, set NaN?
E.g.:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({
    "A": ["A1", "NaN", "A2", "A3"],
    "B": ["B0", "B1", "NaN", "NaN"],
    "C": ["C0", "NaN", "C2", "C3"],
    "D": ["D0", "D1", "D2", "D3"],},
    index=[0, 1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: You're seeking to merge two data frame But your output says you're getting the compare value

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df = df1[df1 == df2]

df

    A    B    C   D
0   A1   B0   C0  D0
1  NaN   B1  NaN  D1
2   A2  NaN   C2  D2
3   A3  NaN   C3  D3
```

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).

Answer (score 0):

Given that df1 and df2 are of the same shape and same index/column names (which you would expect in a direct comparison task like this one), you could just use conditional indexing as:

```
df3 = df1[df1 == df2]
```

Which results in

```
    A   B   C   D
0   A1  B0  C0  D0
1   NaN B1  NaN D1
2   A2  NaN C2  D2
3   A3  NaN C3  D3
```